# Zip files not visible in CWM mode, but visible in ROM Manager in Galaxy S3

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, rom, rom-manager

I copied Super Nexus ROM on my Galaxy S3 i9300 (international version), and flashed the ROM (previously on stock), and it is working fine.

Later, I copied JellyBam ROM, Remix ROM, etc, but I cannot see them in CWM. I can only see the Super Nexus ROM. I installed the later ROMs from ROM Manager (install SD card).

Please help me in finding all the ROMs on my SD Card in CWM.

Comment: Just to confirm my edit, is it correct that you installed the ROMs (JellyBam, Remix) using ROM Manager? This means that you can see the ROMs using ROM Manager, but you cannot see them using CWM. Is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like it could be a byproduct of the multi-user changes added in Android 4.2. Anything you copy over to your phone in 4.2 will not be at the root of the SD card, but rather at  somewhere like `/data/media/0` (where `0` may be a different number depending on which user account you are using on the device). Not entirely sure how it will work with an external SD card in that case (don't have a device with one).